# Where is the subject in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I read this sentence but I'm not sure where the subject is and what I should fill. Could you tell me which one looks okay?

> 1. Throughout the state of Maine **there are** summer music camps, where young people and adults may study in beautiful rural settings.
> 2. Throughout the state of Maine **located** summer music camps, where young people and adults may study in beautiful rural settings.

Comment: *Summer music camps*, upper sentence.

Comment: `Throughout the state of Maine **are located** summer music camps, where young people and adults may study in beautiful rural settings.` This corrected sentence may be acceptable.

Comment: The subject in both sentences is `summer music camps'.

Comment: Hmm, I would have said the sentence, stripped bare, would be: There are camps. and thus the *dummy* subject is the [existential There](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause)

Comment: Can subject behide verb?Throughout the state of Maine **are located** summer music camps.

Comment: @Jim I got the answer key after asking question. Your right, it must be "there are".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sentences that start with "There is/are...", the word "there" is a *dummy* subject and is there only because syntax requires it. The real subject of the sentence follows the linking verb.

In your first example, the subject is "camps". That's why the verb agrees with the plural "camps", as in "there are ... camps", rather than "there is ... camps".

The second example is not grammatically correct, since it's missing the word "are":

> Throughout the state of Maine **are** located summer music camps, where young people and adults may study in beautiful rural settings.

Once the extra "are" is added, the sentence is an example of [subject-verb inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English), and the subject is still "camps".

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that "Summer Music Camps" is the subject. The sentence is explaining where they are and who studies there.